# strange R strptime behavior for week of year

Tags: r, parsing, datetime

Someone please explain this:

```
strptime(c("2010-01", "2010-02"), format="%Y-%W")
[1] "2010-05-21" "2010-05-21"
```

Why May 21st? I'm expecting the first and second weeks of the year (01) and (02) to be in January... %W is week of the year, isn't it?

ISOweek2date in the ISOweek package works:

```
library(ISOweek)
ISOweek2date(c("2010-W01-1", "2010-W02-1"))
[1] "2010-01-04" "2010-01-11"
```

Comment: Haha, and considering it is now May 22nd, I should probably check my code in and stop working for the night. (Thanks for answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the same results as of `ISOweek2date`, you should give `strptime` the same level of details in the time string and format as you did for `ISOweek2date`.

So adding a "-1" for first day in the week in the time string and `-%w` in the format string gives you the same result as `ISOweek2date`:

```
strptime(c("2010-01-1", "2010-02-1"), format="%Y-%W-%w")
#[1] "2010-01-04" "2010-01-11"
```

As mentioned above, without enough information you get the current date

Answer (score 3):

Today is (or at least was) May 21. When you don't provide enough information to get an exact day, R decides to fill in using the current datetime values - e.g. -

```
strptime("2010",format="%Y")
#[1] "2010-05-22 EST"

strptime(c("2010-01", "2010-02"), format="%Y-%W")
#[1] "2010-05-22 EST" "2010-05-22 EST"
```